# I Don't Know What Is Wrong With My Batch File

Tags: batch-file

Help! I am making a batch file that you can make a list of people. Then when someone arrives you can type in their name and it will check if they're on the list. When the batch file checks if the person is on the list it does not work(I am using no capital letters and I am spelling it right) I need to figure out what is wrong with my batch file that is not working.
So the main problem is that when it checks for the person on the list it does not find it. Sorry, im not exactly sure how to phrase this. :)
Here is the code for my program.

```
@echo off
title Event Starter
echo Event Starter
set /p Eventname=Event Name: 
cls
goto :Participants

:Participants
title Name Of Participants
set /p Name1=Name: 
cls
set /p Name2=Name: 
cls
set /p Name3=Name: 
cls
set /p Name4=Name: 
cls
set /p Name5=Name: 
cls
set /p Name6=Name: 
cls
set /p Name7=Name: 
cls
set /p Name8=Name: 
cls
pause
goto :checker

:checker
title Enter Person's Name
echo Enter Who Arrived To Check The Database
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p check1=
goto :database

:database
title Checking Database For The Given Person
echo Checking Database For The Given Person
cls
echo 5 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
cls
echo 20 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
cls
echo 35 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
cls
echo 50 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
cls
echo 70 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
cls
echo 85 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
cls
echo 100 %
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
if %check1%==%Name1% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name2% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name3% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name4% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name5% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name6% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name7% goto :valid
if %check1%==%Name8% goto :valid
goto :invalid

:valid
title %check% Is On The List!
echo %check% Is On The List!
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
pause
goto :checker

:invalid
title %check% Is Not On The List!
echo %check% is Not On The List!
echo This Is Case-Sensative
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
goto :checker
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Some debugging tips: 1) make the smallest non-working program. 2) put lots of echo statements in ("got to line 5; name3 is ..."). 3) when you ask a question, be clear what happens and what you expect to happen.(" I typed 'Jones' . It tried matching Smith, then crashed") 4) give information about your environment / OS (tags help communicate these things)

Answer (score 1):

--EDIT--
Fixed the code. It should work now.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:a
    cls
    set/p name=Name: 
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (File_path) do (
       set name2=%%i
       if /i !name! equ !name2! goto b
       )
    cls
    echo They're not on the list...
    pause
    goto a
:b
    cls
    echo They're on the list...
    pause
    goto a
```

The script goes through the file checking if the user-defined name (`name`) is within it. If it is then it sends it to `:b` which reports back to you saying that they were on the list. You could modify this into a function by replacing the `goto` command with `exit /b 2` for true (they were on the list) and `exit /b 3` for false (they weren't).

The names should each be on a separate line, demonstrated below. Capitalization doesn't matter because of the `/i` switch on the `if` command.

```
Mark Finch
Julie Fernz
Tom Riddle...
```

Comment: Again, please test your scripts before you post, as it won't work this way. `if %name% equ %name2%` fails inside a block, you need to use delayed expansion instead `if !name! equ !name2!`. And the file doesn't need commas, each name need an own line

Comment: I fixed it and made it all nice. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, there is a lot of unnecessary lines there, so instead of pinpointing the error I have rewritten your script into a much cleaner version, which should hopefully solve the problems you were having as well! :)

```
@echo off
title Event Starter
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Event Starter
set /p Eventname=Event Name: 
cls
title Name Of Participants
for /l %%a in (1,1,8) do (
set /p Name[%%a]=Name: 
cls
)

:checker
title Enter Person's Name
echo Enter Who Arrived To Check The Database
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p check1=

title Checking Database For The Given Person
echo Checking Database For The Given Person
cls
for %%b in (5,20,35,50,70,85,100) do (
echo %percent%%
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 6 > nul
cls
)
for /l %%a in (1,1,8) do (
if !check1!==!Name[%%a]! goto :valid
)
goto :invalid

:valid
title %check% Is On The List!
echo %check% Is On The List!
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
goto :checker

:invalid
title %check% Is Not On The List!
echo %check% is Not On The List!
echo This Is Case-Sensative
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
goto :checker
```

Comment: Bali C, i tried out the code you reposted and when it checks for the person in the database it says, ECHO OFF and it stays like that like forever. It does not check the database

Comment: @user2045195 Sorry, I missed out a critical line, try now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the syntax, but there is a difference between the way you input the initial names (e.g. `set /p Name1=Name:` ) and how you input the name to check (`set /p check1=` ). Is that significant?